# Different strings resource files for varying screens density

Tags: android, android-resources, android-screen-support

I have several strings that need to be shown in a single line according to my app design.

The problem is for lower density screens (especially those lower than 2.0), my texts are overlapping each other. That's why I was thinking if android allows creating different string resources file for different screen densities. So that I would have 2 string resources:

For lower-density screens:

```
 <string name="valid_until_x">Действ.: %s</string>
```

and for higher density screens:

```
 <string name="valid_until_x">Действителен до: %s</string>
```

I did a little bit of my research and could not find anything related to this. Has Android covered this or it is something that I am going to deep?

If it is too deep, should I be checking screen density with `if` statements every time and provide much shorter versions of my strings for lower densities? E.g. shortening text "Действителен до: 15.12.2020" to "Действ.: 15.12.2020"

Comment: Your problem is not really related to screen density. For example, the user could go into Settings and change their font size. Or, the user could have a really small screen and the words do not fit. Or, your strings in another language might be a lot longer. Use the autosize options with your `TextView` to have the font scale to allow your text to fit the desired space.

Comment: @CommonsWare I checked out the autosize property looks like it is available since API level 26. My current min API level is 21.

Comment: If you are using `AppCompatActivity`, autosize (using the `app:` prefix for the XML attributes) works on older devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare For some wierd reason `app` namespace is not recognized. I am using `AppCompatActivity`. Version: `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02` . Should I be using non-androidx one?

Comment: I mean `app:autoSizeTextType` is not recognized. Or is it some kind of bug by AS?

Comment: I am uncertain what you mean by "not recognized". In AS 3.6.1, with `1.1.0` of `appcompat`, I do not get any warnings in Studio for `app:autoSizeTextType` in a layout resource.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you. Looks like I have to manually type whole line of xml code. I was surprised that AS did not suggest me `autoSizeTextType` when I am typing. I am leaning my lessons that I should never trust lint suggestion by AS.

Comment: Ah, yes, Studio does not offer autocomplete for that. I do not know what Studio's rules are for what is and is not available for autocomplete in the `app:` namespace.

Comment: @CommonsWare It is sometimes happens for Kotlin code as well. AS does not suggest anything but when I type my code AS does not complain that code is incorrect and code works completely fine. Happens mainly when working with `Koin` DI library.